# Access getContentResolver() inside of a BaseAdapter

Tags: android, android-contacts, baseadapter

I needed some help with one of my new android projects. Let me just quickly explain the structure.

My project has a MainActivity and within the activity I have 3 fragments which are accessible via the tabs on the app. On my very last tab/fragment I am trying to list all of the contacts on the phone along with a picture, name and number. I came across the following code for the name and number:

```
Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
            String name = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
            String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            String full = name + " " + phoneNumber;


        }
```

The following code works like a charm if I place it within my fragment and name change certain references like `getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);`
to `getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);`

anyway, so I have been able to get that to work, but fell onto problems like listing the contacts with images on the left side, so I came across a YouTube tutorial [Android BaseAdapter Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ka5Tk7J9rG0). After a lot of facepalm moments and trying to figure out what on earth is going on (I am new to Android development) I finally got through the first 2 tutorials and landed on a small problem.

Trying to create access the contacts (using the first block of code in this question) I discovered that I cannot do so as the function `getContentResolver()` is not accessible unless if it is within a Activity. Here is my current code for my BaseAdapter: [Android BaseAdapter Test Code - Paste Bin](http://pastebin.com/GsKEX8hG).

It would help me out so much if someone could direct me on the best way to approach this.

On a side note, is there any better way of accessing contacts and just simply listing them out with picture, name and number? A library maybe? Anything super simple works; WhatsApp like contact listing even, or Viber? Thanks!

Comment: Add a context argument to the constructor of the adapter and store it in the instance. As long as your adapter is not statically stored or stores the context in a static variable this is the easiest way. Even better, get the contacts outside of the adapter and then simply assign the list to the adapter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to call `getContentResolver()` you need a `Context` object of your activity, you have to ways to do this when using the `BaseAdapter` class.

**1. Pass it via constructor -**
Inside your adapter:

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;

    public MyBaseAdapter (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // Do your stuff
}
```

Inside your activity:

```
MyBaseAdapter myBaseAdapter = new MyBaseAdapter(getApplicationContext());
```

**2. Get the context from the view-**

```
public class MyBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        //BaseAdpter stuff

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if(inflater == null){
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            }
            //BaseAdpter stuff
            return convertView;
        }

}
```

Then just call `context.getContentResolver()`.